# Reduction of RE and Rec languages

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

Suppose $L_1$ is reduces to $L_2$ in polynomial time, $L_1\leq_p^\mathsf{}L_2.$ we know that if $L_2$ is RE then $L_1$ is also RE and  $L_2$ is REC then $L_1$ is also REC.

And  also I know that if $L_1$ is REC then $L_2$ is RE **and** REC is false. Because by taking counterexample $L_1=\emptyset$ and $L_2=$halting problem.
So see from this example **and** case fails to prove above postulation.

My first question is that **or** case could be true. I mean if $L_1$ is REC then $L_2$ is RE **or** REC$-$could it be true?

My second question "if if $L_1$ is RE then $L_2$ is also RE" $-$ could it be true?
I don't want any details proof. I want counterexample for true and false case.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144846/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4279212/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L_1$ is recursive and $L_1 \le_p L_2$, they it is possible that $L_2$ is not recursively enumerable (and hence not recursive).

For example pick $L_1 = \emptyset$ and $L_2$ as the set of (a suitable encoding of) all Turing machines that do not halt on empty input.
Clearly $L_2$ is not recursively enumerable. A possible Karp reduction from $L_1$ to $L_2$ is the constant function that returns (the encoding of) a Turing machine that immediately halts.

If $L_1$ is recursively enumerable and $L_1 \le_p L_2$ then it **might** be the case that $L_2$ is also recursively enumerable. For example pick $L_1 = L_2 = \emptyset$, a Karp reduction from $L_1$ to $L_2$ is the identity function. Notice that, in this example, $L_1$ is also recursive.

Comment: How from L1 to L2 is the constant function,L1 isn't contain any string. You mean constant function is from element $\phi$ in $L_1$ to $L_2$ ,set of (a suitable encoding of) all Turing machines that do not halt on empty input? Am I right?

Comment: I never said that the function is from $L_1$ to $L_2$. The function is from $\Sigma^*$ to $\Sigma^*$, where $\Sigma$ is the alphabet of both $L_1$ and $L_2$. I said that the function is a Karp reduction from $L_1$ to $L_2$. A Karp-reduction from $L_1$ to $L_2$ is a polynomial-time computable total function $f : \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ such that $x \in L_1 \iff f(x) \in L_2$.  See the definition of [Many-one reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction) and of [Karp reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Many-one_reductions).

Comment: You mean constant function is from element ϕ in L1 to L2 ,set of (a suitable encoding of) all Turing machines that do not halt on empty input? Am I right?

Comment: No. The domain of the function is not $L_1$ and the codomain of the function is not $L_2$. In fact, the image of the function (a set with single element) is disjoint from $L_2$.

Comment: You mean constant function is from element ϕ in L1 to set of (a suitable encoding of) all Turing machines that do not halt on empty input in L2? Am I right?

Comment: Give one element in L1 which makes mapping with L2 element? I mean give example of x,such that x∈L1⟺f(x)∈L2.

Comment: All $x$ in $\Sigma^*$ satisfy that condition (by definition of Karp reduction). If you insist on a concrete example pick $x=\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ denotes the empty word.

Comment: But my one confusion L1 has no element. How can I take Epsilon?

Comment: The **function** is from $\Sigma^*$ to $\Sigma^*$, not from $L_1$ to $L_2$. The **reduction** is from $L_1$ to $L_2$. I'm sorry, I don't know how to explain it better. Have a good day.

Comment: "A possible Karp reduction from L1 to L2 is the constant function that returns (the encoding of) a Turing machine that immediately halts."-- what does it mean ? It makes $L_2$ is RE? Please tell. It is very important to know.. Please reply